# Creating multiple nested loops to generate two numbers that move through the length of a Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop, nested

As the title reads, I have been thinking about creating multiple nested loops that aim to achieve one purpose. Move two generated random numbers between 0-9 through each possible possition of an array.

For example, App generates first number (fNum) 1 and second number (sNum) 6. It then moves these numbers in the array which containts ABC. However firstNum and secondNum will need to also try all the possible combinations, so each one will need to be different with each loop.

```
-1ABC6
-A1BC6
-AB1C6
-ABC16
-ABC61
-AB6C1
-A6BC1
-6ABC1
-A6B1C
-A61BC
-A16BC
-A1B6C
-A1BC6
```

and so on...

I beleive the best way will be to create a method for generating a counter, which increments the numbers which I can call.

```
    private int getNextNumber(int num) {

    if (num == 0) {
        return num;
    } else {
        num++;
    }

    if (num < 10) {
        return num;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Then I will need multiple nested loops... I have decided to go for several loops which will go infinitly.

```
            while (j < maxlen) {
            //J = 0 and maxlen = length of text so in this case 3 as it is ABC
            //Add two numbers and check against answer

            while (fNum != -1 || sNum != -1) {

                //incrememnt numbers
                fNum = getNextNumber(fNum);
                System.out.println(fNum);

                sNum = getNextNumber(sNum);
                System.out.println(fNum);

            }

            String textIni = "ABC";
            int lenOfText = textIni.length();
            char[] split = textIni.toCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < lenOfText; i++) {
                //here it will look at the length of the Text and
                //try the possible positions it could be at....
                //maybe wiser to do a longer loop but I am not too sure
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should look into recursion ad this look to be solvable using recursion!

Comment: Do you have to store those permutations ? If that is the case, a recursive solution would be a better choice. If you need to perform a treatment on each permutation without storing it, stick to an iterative solution

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Recursion, I have herd of the term however I am still a noob when it comes to Java, ok thanks! I will try to solve this problem through the use and report back.

Comment: @Tom Hi, the questions sorry I just noticed I haven't put it in, was how can I actually go through the array and check against all the possibilities, I am now trying to learn recursion so that I may come up with a solution.

Comment: @Dici I dont need to store them, I just need to test against a case I have for example if it equals to 1A5BC then break. Is recursion still the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: @zhiar No, I will propose you another solution in addition to the resursive one (for culture)

Comment: @zhiar Do you need a general solution for any number of additional elements or only 2 is enough ? Not to nention that it is more straighforward if you don't need a general answer

Comment: @Dici only two random numbers is enough. But both numbers will also need to be randomized between the numbers of 0 - 9.

Comment: @Dici also it will need to be available to tackle any length of array... I am guessing this will make things difficult?

Comment: @zhiar No, it won't be a problem (using `ArrayList`). Check on my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't need to store all possible combinations, we will save some memory using only `O(n)` storage with an iterative solution. I propose you a basic implementation but don't expect to use it on large arrays since it has a `O(n³)` complexity.

```
public static void generateCombinationsIterative(List<Integer> original, int fnum, int snum) {
    int size = original.size();
    for (int i=0 ; i<=size ; i++) {
        List<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>(original);
        tmp.add(i,fnum);
        for (int j=0 ; j<=size + 1 ; j++) {
            tmp.add(j,snum);
            System.out.print(tmp + (i == size && j == size + 1 ? "" : ", "));
            tmp.remove(j);
        }
    }
}
```

For your culture, here is an example of a recursive solution, which takes a lot of memory so don't use it if you don't need to generate the lists of results. Nevertheless, this is a more general solution that can deal with any number of elements to insert.

```
public static List<List<Integer>> generateCombinations(List<Integer> original, Deque<Integer> toAdd) {
    if (toAdd.isEmpty()) {
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.add(original);
        return res;
    }

    int element = toAdd.pop();
    List<List<Integer>> res = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i=0 ; i<=original.size() ; i++) 
        // you must make a copy of toAdd, otherwise each recursive call will perform
        // a pop() on it and the result will be wrong
        res.addAll(generateCombinations(insertAt(original,element,i),new LinkedList<>(toAdd)));
    return res;
}

// a helper function for a clear code
public static List<Integer> insertAt(List<Integer> input, int element, int index) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(input);
    result.add(index,element);
    return result;
}
```

Note that I did not use any array in order to benefit from dynamic data structures, however you can call the methods like this :

```
int[] arr  = { 1,2,3 };
int   fnum = 4, snum = 5;
generateCombinationsIterative(Arrays.asList(arr),fnum,snum);
generateCombinations(Arrays.asList(arr),new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(fnum,snum));
```

Note that both methods generate the combinations in the same order.

Comment: System.out.print(tmp + (i == size && j == size + 1 ? "" : ", ");  is missing a ) somewhere but cannot figure it out! also can I use the following pseudo code - int[] arr = (a string to array)?

Comment: @zhiar Fixed the missing bracket, thanks. I gave you a code using integers but you can replace it by chars (`int` becomes `char` and `Integer` becomes `Character`).

Comment: Thanks again, however as I suspected when I replace the int with char it gives me an error as both fNum and sNum are int's, they cannot be converted to chars when you add them to the array. Any solution to this problem? do I need to also convert these two numbers to chars in order to be able to add them to the array later on?

Comment: This is not very elegant, but you can convert an int (between 0 and 9) to a char using `String.valueOf(myInt).charAt(0)`

Comment: I promise final question :) you have advised me to use generateCombinationsIterative(Arrays.asList(arr),fnum,snum); to call the method however I cannot actually call this as it is no longer a type but a char due to changing the list to Character.

The error:
incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: Character
    lower bounds: char[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>asList(T...)

Comment: `char[]` is not compatible with `Character`, that is why you are getting this error

Comment: So what can I do to get rid of this? Does the code need to be re done?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you have to create a helper function that fills a `Character[]` or a `List<Characters>` with the characters of an input string. It is easy but not really satisfying to have to write such code. Sometimes, the fact that Java keep using primitive types lead to that kind of issues you would not have in a pure object language

Comment: so something like 
'String tmp = "ABC";
        int length = tmp.length();
        char c[] = new char[length];
        tmp.getChars(0, length, c, 0);'

Comment: No, it must use the wrapper class `Character` so your output must be a `Character[]` or a `List<Character>`.

Comment: So how do you pass it in, could you show me an example to implement, sorry it is my first time dealing with this.

Comment: and then use something like List<Character> arr = toCharacters("String"); to feed the String in?

Comment: You probably don't need to keep it in a variable : `generateCombinationsIterative(toCharacters(myString),fnum,snum)`

Comment: Your amazing!! thanks so much for your help today ;) I havent yet tested it all together but im sure it will not have any problems!